# what is equivalent to SET verify off in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

When I run my shell script so much of java error handling messages get displayed every single time I ran it.

I want an option of not display it to the screen for now since I am testing.

Is there a way to do this?

the way I have it right now is:

```
./load_data.sh TCOMPASS/Protocol >> load_semantic.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect standard error:

```
./load_data.sh TCOMPASS/Protocol >> load_semantic.log 2>/dev/null
```